# Pegar primeiro item de cada objeto em uma resposta JSON

Tags: javascript, algoritmo

- Estou obtendo um json através da seguinte URL: http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos (via GET)
- Estou iterando sobre os objetos, mas queria pegar apenas o primeiro
  item de cada objeto, que no caso seria  URL.
- Como faço isso?

  ```
  axios.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos").then((response) => {
      var data = response.data;
      for(i in data){
          console.log(response.data[i])
      }
  });
  ```

Comment: estava atualizando, amigo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você já passou o response pra variável data. Pode fazer assim, verificando se a variável é diferente do valor de `albumId`:

```js
var data = [
  {
    "albumId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952"
  },
  {
    "albumId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "reprehenderit est deserunt velit ipsam",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/771796",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/771796"
  },
  {
    "albumId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "officia porro iure quia iusto qui ipsa ut modi",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/24f355",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/24f355"
  },
  {
    "albumId": 2,
    "id": 51,
    "title": "non sunt voluptatem placeat consequuntur rem incidunt",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/8e973b",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/8e973b"
  },
  {
    "albumId": 2,
    "id": 52,
    "title": "eveniet pariatur quia nobis reiciendis laboriosam ea",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/121fa4",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/121fa4"
  },
];

// variável de controle para não pegar o mesmo id
var albumId;

for(let i in data){
   // atribui o valor de albumId a variável id
   let id = data[i].albumId;
   // se for diferente, pega o valor da url
   if(albumId != id){
      // redefine o valor da variável com o valor atual
      albumId = id;
      console.log(data[i].url);
   }
}
```

De repente você pode criar uma array e ir adicionando as urls para depois fazer o que quiser com elas:

```js
var data = [
  {
    "albumId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952"
  },
  {
    "albumId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "reprehenderit est deserunt velit ipsam",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/771796",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/771796"
  },
  {
    "albumId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "officia porro iure quia iusto qui ipsa ut modi",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/24f355",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/24f355"
  },
  {
    "albumId": 2,
    "id": 51,
    "title": "non sunt voluptatem placeat consequuntur rem incidunt",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/8e973b",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/8e973b"
  },
  {
    "albumId": 2,
    "id": 52,
    "title": "eveniet pariatur quia nobis reiciendis laboriosam ea",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/121fa4",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/121fa4"
  },
];

// cria a array
var urls = [];

// variável de controle para não pegar o mesmo id
var albumId;

for(let i in data){
   // atribui o valor de albumId a variável id
   let id = data[i].albumId;
   // se for diferente, pega o valor da url
   if(albumId != id){
      // redefine o valor da variável com o valor atual
      albumId = id;
      // adiciona as urls à array
      urls.push(data[i].url);
   }
}

// percorre a array
for(let url of urls){
   console.log(url);
}
```

Comment: Exatamente amigo. No entanto, preciso pegar a primeira url de cada albumId. Ex: Quando o albumId for igual a 1, eu pego a primeira url e pulo para o albumId 2.

Comment: Agora saquei...

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, perfeito a sua explicação!

Comment: o legal é que o cara fez a mesma logica que a minha

Comment: @Gunblades nem tinha visto a sua resposta.

Answer (score 2):

```js
      var data = [
      {
        "albumId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt",
        "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952",
        "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952"
      },
      {
        "albumId": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "title": "reprehenderit est deserunt velit ipsam",
        "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/771796",
        "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/771796"
      },
      {
        "albumId": 1,
        "id": 3,
        "title": "officia porro iure quia iusto qui ipsa ut modi",
        "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/24f355",
        "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/24f355"
      },
      {
        "albumId": 2,
        "id": 51,
        "title": "non sunt voluptatem placeat consequuntur rem incidunt",
        "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/8e973b",
        "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/8e973b"
      },
      {
        "albumId": 2,
        "id": 52,
        "title": "eveniet pariatur quia nobis reiciendis laboriosam ea",
        "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/121fa4",
        "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/121fa4"
      },
    ];

    var aux = ""
    
    for(i in data){
        if (data[i].albumId != aux){
            console.log(data[i].url)
            aux = data[i].albumId
        }
        
    }
```

Eu acredito que seria algo do tipo:

onde `url` pode ser qualquer atributo do JSON:

- albumId
- id
- title
- url
- thumbnailUrl

Comment: No caso eu queria pegar a primeira url de cada albumId. Por ex: existem 5 fotos com o mesmo albumId. Quero pegar somente a primeira url dessas fotos.

Comment: por exemplo no Id 1 https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952 e no 2 https://via.placeholder.com/600/8e973b ???

Comment: Issooooo, exatamente.

Comment: Pegar a primeira foto, de cada albumId

Comment: testa ai eu acho que colocando esse if já resolva seu problema

Comment: Qual if, amigo?

Comment: Esse : `if (data[i].albumId != aux)`

Comment: Aux se refere ao que?

Comment: Acho que seu navegador ta cacheando a pagina tenta recarregar com Ctrl + F5 e visualize minha resposta editada.

Comment: Não consegui :/

Comment: Não entendi muito bem esse lance do aux

Comment: Isso é uma função própria do javascript?

Comment: é uma variável auxiliar, por boas praticas escrevi aux para identificar ela melhor.